# Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\SERVICIOSUNARP\index.php on line 57

Tags: php, undefined

Tengo este arreglo que viene como respuesta de un webservice

```
var_dump=$miarreglo;
```

resultado:

```
array(1) { 

["respuestaTitularidad"]=> array(4) 
{ 

[0]=> array(10) 
{ 
    ["registro"]=> string(30) "REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD INMUEBLE" 
    ["libro"]=> string(19) "REGISTRO DE PREDIOS" 
    ["apPaterno"]=> string(7) "SANCHEZ" 
    ["apMaterno"]=> string(5) "ROJAS" 
    ["nombre"]=> string(15) "JORGE EDILBERTO" 
    ["numeroPartida"]=> string(8) "45043150" 
    ["estado"]=> string(6) "ACTIVA" 
    ["zona"]=> string(29) "ZONA REGISTRAL IX - SEDE LIMA" 
    ["oficina"]=> string(4) "LIMA" 
    ["direccion"]=> string(85) "CALLE LOS AGRICOLAS MZ R LOTE 33 , LAS ACACIAS DE MONTERRICO LA MOLINA - LIMA - LIMA" 
} 


[1]=> array(10) 
{ 
    ["registro"]=> string(30) "REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD INMUEBLE" 
    ["libro"]=> string(19) "REGISTRO DE PREDIOS" 
    ["apPaterno"]=> string(7) "SANCHEZ" 
    ["apMaterno"]=> string(5) "ROJAS" 
    ["nombre"]=> string(5) "JORGE" 
    ["numeroPartida"]=> string(8) "43140671" 
    ["estado"]=> string(6) "ACTIVA" 
    ["zona"]=> string(29) "ZONA REGISTRAL IX - SEDE LIMA" 
    ["oficina"]=> string(4) "LIMA" 
    ["direccion"]=> string(84) "JIRON LAS ANEMONAS MZ 54 LOTE 14 URB LAS FLORES SAN JUAN DE LURIGANCHO - LIMA - LIMA" 
} 

[2]=> array(13) { 
    ["registro"]=> string(26) "REGISTRO DE BIENES MUEBLES" 
    ["libro"]=> string(31) "REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD VEHICULAR" 
    ["apPaterno"]=> string(7) "SANCHEZ" 
    ["apMaterno"]=> string(5) "ROJAS" 
    ["nombre"]=> string(10) "JORGE LUIS" 
    ["tipoDocumento"]=> string(8) "C.M. " 
    ["numeroDocumento"]=> string(9) "116770700" 
    ["numeroPartida"]=> string(8) "50438525" 
    ["numeroPlaca"]=> string(7) "HG5186 " 
    ["estado"]=> string(6) "ACTIVA" 
    ["zona"]=> string(29) "ZONA REGISTRAL IX - SEDE LIMA" 
    ["oficina"]=> string(4) "LIMA" 
    ["direccion"]=> string(9) "#########" 
}

 [3]=> array(13) { 
     ["registro"]=> string(26) "REGISTRO DE BIENES MUEBLES" 
     ["libro"]=> string(31) "REGISTRO DE PROPIEDAD VEHICULAR" 
     ["apPaterno"]=> string(7) "SANCHEZ" 
     ["apMaterno"]=> string(5) "ROJAS" 
     ["nombre"]=> string(12) "JORGE MARTIN" 
     ["tipoDocumento"]=> string(3) "DNI" 
     ["numeroDocumento"]=> string(8) "44617981" 
     ["numeroPartida"]=> string(8) "51030901" 
     ["numeroPlaca"]=> string(7) "BIA898 " 
     ["estado"]=> string(6) "ACTIVA" 
     ["zona"]=> string(29) "ZONA REGISTRAL IX - SEDE LIMA" 
     ["oficina"]=> string(4) "LIMA" 
     ["direccion"]=> string(9) "#########" 
 } 


} 
}
```

Como puedo leer los datos del arreglo? ya que necesito colocar la información en tablas, ya que el siguiente código no me funciona.

```
<?php foreach ($miarreglo as $data) {  ?>

<tr> 

  <td><center><?php echo $data->registro;   ?></center> </td>
  <td><center><?php echo $data->libro;   ?></center> </td>
  <td><center><?php echo $data->apPaterno;   ?></center> </td>
  <td><center><?php echo $data->apMaterno;   ?></center> </td>
  <td><center> <?php echo $data->nombre;  ?></center> </td>
  <td><center> <?php echo $data->numeroPartida;  ?></center> </td>
  <td><center><?php echo  $data->estado;   ?></center> </td>
  <td><center><?php echo $data->zona;   ?></center> </td>
    <td><center><?php echo  $data->oficina;   ?></center> </td>
  <td><center><?php echo $data->direccion;   ?></center> </td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>
```

> Notice: Undefined index: registro in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\SERVICIOSUNARP\index.php on line 55

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si observas bien tienes los `array` que quieres imprimir dentro de otro `array`, por lo cual deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```
<?php foreach ($miarreglo['respuestaTitularidad'] as $data) {  ?>

<tr> 
  <td><center><?php echo $data['registro']; ?></center> </td>
  <td><center><?php echo $data['libro']; ?></center> </td>
  <td><center><?php echo $data['apPaterno']; ?></center> </td>
  <td><center><?php echo $data['apMaterno']; ?></center> </td>
  <td><center> <?php echo $data['nombre'];?></center> </td>
  <td><center> <?php echo $data['numeroPartida'];?></center> </td>
  <td><center><?php echo  $data['estado']; ?></center> </td>
  <td><center><?php echo $data['zona']; ?></center> </td>
  <td><center><?php echo  $data['oficina']; ?></center> </td>
  <td><center><?php echo $data['direccion']; ?></center> </td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!! me ha funcionado

Comment: Si te funcionó te invito a que consideres marcar como aceptada la respuesta, esto con el fin de que próximos desarrolladores sepan que fue la solución correcta, además te invito a que te hagas el [tour] para que sepas cual es el funcionamiento del sitio y ganes tu primer medalla...Bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español !

Answer (score 1):

Sería de la siguiente manera:

`<?php foreach ($miarreglo as $data) { ?>
<tr>`

<td><center><?php echo $data['registro']; ?></center> </td>
<td><center><?php echo $data['libro']; ?></center> </td>
<td><center><?php echo $data['apPaterno']; ?></center> </td>
<td><center><?php echo $data['apMaterno']; ?></center> </td>
<td><center> <?php echo $data['nombre']; ?></center> </td>
<td><center> <?php echo $data['numeroPartida']; ?></center> </td>
<td><center><?php echo $data['estado']; ?></center> </td>
<td><center><?php echo $data['zona']; ?></center> </td>
<td><center><?php echo $data['oficina']; ?></center> </td>
<td><center><?php echo $data['direccion']; ?></center> </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>

saludos.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: registro in 
    C:\xampp\htdocs\www\SERVICIOSUNARP\index.php on line 55

Para cada una de las lineas.